# Sample random vector meeting constraint

Tags: vectors, sampling

I'd like to sample a vector $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $\frac{\mathbf{x_i}}{|\mathbf{x}|}\geq c$ for all $i$ where $c \in [0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}]$. Is this possible? How can this be done?

So far, what I've been doing is randomly sampling a uniform distribution with a small interval and accepting the sample when the constraint is met.

Comment: It depends on the value of $c$. If $c > 1$ then it won't be possible since $x_{i}/|x|\leq 1$

Comment: How is the $\mathbf{x}$ in the denominator related to the $\mathbf{x}_i$?

Comment: @pwerth I updated the question so that $c\in[0,1]$. It should still work for my purposes.

Comment: What kind of distribution do you expect?

Comment: @CalvinGodfrey $x_i$ is meant to be the $i$-th dimension of $x$.

Comment: @dafinguzman Normal or uniform would be nice. I just need random variation in the vector values of $x$.

Comment: Immediately, that tells us that for $c > \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, it is impossible to generate a vector in $n$ dimensions or higher. (Thanks @dafinguzman for that catch!)

Comment: Yes, $c$ is bound to be at most $1/\sqrt{n}$

Comment: Just did some rough calculations and I think even $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ will work as an upper bound. Updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z^i$ be the vector whose coordinates are all equal to $c$, except for the $i^{th}$ coordinate which is $\sqrt{1-(k-1)c^2}$. Note that $|z^i|=1$, and each coordinate of $z^i$ is at least $c$. Therefore, $z^i$ is a vector which fulfills your constraints.

Furthermore, any convex combination of the vectors $z^i$ will fulfill your constraints. To see this, note that if $\lambda_i$ is a list of positive numbers summing to one, and $z=\sum \lambda_i z^i$, then using the triangle inequality,
$$
z_j=\sum_i \lambda_iz^i_j\ge c\sum \lambda_i |z^i|=c\sum  |\lambda_iz^i|\ge c\left|\sum_i \lambda_i z^i\right|=c|z|
$$

Therefore, one valid method is to randomly choose $k$ positive numbers $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ summing to $1$, and let ${\bf x}=\sum_i \lambda_i z_i$. To do this, see [simplex sampling](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3227/uniform-sampling-from-a-simplex).

To add a little more variety, you instead let ${\bf x}=R\sum_i \lambda_i z_i$, where $R$ is any positive random scalar. As long as the support of $R$ is $(0,\infty)$, then the support of this sampling method is the set of all admissible vectors.